# Random numbers with a gap

Tags: c, random

In C how can I get random numbers in a certain gap? 
Like, for example, get a random number between the numbers 5 and 25.

I already tried to subtract like this:

```
srand((int) time(NULL));
numero = rand()%max-min;
```

And also tried to make a do-while cycle, but it never reached an end.

Comment: (welcome to *posting* to SO!) This looks *from a certain range* much more than `in a certain gap`. I thought you had a precedence error until I got what you were trying. Please edit into your post: Do you need *exactly* uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to generate random numbers between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive) is

```
rand() % (max-min) + min;
```

However the statistical properties of these numbers might not be very good because the lower digits of the numbers generated by `rand()` tend to have shorter cycles.

Comment: Will generate values from min to max - 1 rather then min to max inclusive.

Comment: @Clifford: Yes, that's what I wrote. It is not clear from the original post which boundary value(s) should be included.

Comment: You did say that - apologies.   Your point about the least-significant digits of `rand()` will be implementation dependent, but even with a perfect `rand()` there is a bias whenever the right-and operand of the `%` is not a factor of `RAND_MAX+1` .

Answer (score 0):

For situations where a small bias is not critical for min to max inclusive:

```
numero = rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min ;
```

statistically bias free random is a little more involved but often unnecessary in many applications and when `max + 1 - min` is small compared to `RAND_MAX`.